# igraph & POSIXct

Tags: r, posix, igraph

I have the following data

```
library(data.table); library(igraph)
t <- data.table(a=seq(ISOdate(2019,1,1), ISOdate(2019,7,1), "months"), 
                b=seq(ISOdate(2019,1,2), ISOdate(2019,7,2), "months"))
g <- graph_from_edgelist(as.matrix(t[,c("a","b")]))
```

and would like to apply `subcomponent(g,ISOdate(2019,1,1),"out")` but obtain the error that

```
 At structural_properties.c:1249 : subcomponent failed, Invalid vertex id
```

Is anyone aware of a solution to this problem?

**Additional complication**

The problem is complicated when I have an additional variable

```
start <- seq(ISOdate(2019,1,1), ISOdate(2019,7,1), "months")[c(1,3,5,7)]
```

that contains different starting vertices. Again, `subcomponent(g,start,"out")` gives the error above. Is there a workaround, similar to Ben's suggestion in the comments for the case above?

Comment: Your `v` argument needs to be specified using the vertex ID not the name. Try: 

`subcomponent(g, V(g)$name == ISOdate(2019,1,1),"out")`

Comment: Ah, my mistake! But what happens when I use a vector for `v`? I have added an edit above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally you could use the `match` function or the `%in%` operator. However, the `subcomponent`-function only allows for single queries.  In order for this to work, I needed to adapt your `start` vector, because the timezone was added there but not in the original graph:

```
start <- gsub(" GMT", "", start)
```

So to answer your question (building on my comment from above): You could use the `adjacent_vertices` function, which queries multiple vertices at once.

```
adjacent_vertices(g, V(g)$name %in% start, mode = "out")
```

The drawback here is, that only the target vertices are being reported and not the start vertices. I am unaware of an existing function that corrects this. So in order to get both start and target vertices, you could write your own function:

```
lapply(1:length(start), function(x) subcomponent(g, V(g)$name == start[x], "out"))
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: I did some trial & error and found that `adjacent_vertices` seems impractical for my purposes because I need it to return more distant vertices as well. But of course, this wasn't part of the question. `subcomponent(.)` may still work because the function is nested within a data.table grouping and therefore needs to query only one vertex at a time. But somehow, it returns an empty vector. Feel free to take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57003667/igraph-posix-and-data-table where I describe the problem in more detail.